# How do I add order note on (advanced) custom fields update?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'd like to add an order note to log the time I added tracking number to existing order. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to store trackings. Tried function below, and it breaks my site:

```
function tt_add_tracking_note( $order ) {

    $tt_order = $order->id;

    if (get_field('tt-track', $tt_order)) {
        $tt_tracknum_note = 'Added tracking number ' . the_field('tt-track', $tt_order);
    }

    $tt_order->add_order_note( $tt_tracknum_note );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'tt_add_tracking_note', 10, 2 );
```

What is wrong and how do I add a note the right way?

Comment: `$tt_order` contains `$order_ID` then `$tt_order->add_order_note(` doesn't works. try instead `$order->add_order_note(...`

Comment: @Kaperto still error in PHP, see log below:

Comment: #0 *******/class-wp-hook.php(288): tt_add_tracking_note(23002, Object(WP_Post))
#1 *******/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 *******/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 *******/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php(218): do_action('woocommerce_pro...', 23002, Object(WP_Post))
#4 *******/class-wp-hook.php(290): WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->save_meta_boxes(23002, Object(WP_Post))
#5 *******/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array